# How to log changes on update with triggers?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to log changes (updates) on the 'users' table in a `logs` table.

I haven't tried but I thought about running a second query that inserts data on the `logs` table every time I update something in the `users` table.

It is a viable solution but I would have to run a query to get the old values, run another query to insert the `users` update and finally insert the old values in the `logs`.

This is how I update data on `users`:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET username = '$newUserName' WHERE username = '$userName'";
$res = $conn->query($sql);
if ($conn->query($sql) === true) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $newUserName;
    echo "Username changed.";
} else {
    echo $conn->error;
}
```

I want to take the old value in the `users` table, (the primary key of the row that has been updated, called `user_id`), the table and field affected, and the value that actually chagned.

So for example, I update users.username in the row with `test@1234.test` as primary key from `Alice` to `Bob`, the row in `logs` will have `test@1234.test` as `user_id`, `users` as table and `username` as field, with `Alice` as `old_value`.

How can I do this with triggers?

Comment: Read manual, code trigger, Add trigger code to question if it doesn't work or fails to syntax. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL, you can use a code similar to this:

First, create the log table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users_history;
CREATE TABLE users_history LIKE users; -- inherit fields from your users table
ALTER TABLE users_history DROP COLUMN id; -- drop and recreate identifying colums in users table (examples here), to recreate in a fine-tuned way
ALTER TABLE users_history DROP COLUMN identifier;
ALTER TABLE users_history  ADD COLUMN identifier VARCHAR(255) FIRST;
ALTER TABLE users_history  ADD COLUMN identifier VARCHAR(255) FIRST;
ALTER TABLE users_history  ADD COLUMN id INT UNSIGNED FIRST;
ALTER TABLE users_history  ADD INDEX (id);
ALTER TABLE users_history  ADD COLUMN action ENUM('UPDATE','INSERT','DELETE') FIRST;
ALTER TABLE users_history  ADD COLUMN user VARCHAR(255) FIRST; -- the MySQL user who perform edits
ALTER TABLE users_history  ADD COLUMN mdate TIMESTAMP FIRST;
ALTER TABLE users_history  ADD INDEX (mdate);
```

Then create the trigger that will populate the log table on updates.

```
CREATE TRIGGER users_history_update AFTER UPDATE ON users
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        INSERT INTO users_history SET 
        user =  USER(), -- the MySQL user who performed the edit
        action = 'UPDATE',
        id = OLD.id, 
        identifier = OLD.identifier, 
        username = OLD.username
        -- , [...] possibly other fields you want to track
    ;
END;
```

This is modified (to fit the table of the OP) from a full MySQL example I wrote at https://bibus-biblio.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Automatic_creation_of_an_edit_history_using_MySQL_5
(see that link for the context: creation of more tables, other triggers for INSERT and DELETE actions).

Comment: This post was deleted by a moderator with comment "Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions."
Clearly, this post is very different from my other post at https://stackoverflow.com/a/76884757/9071968. My answer in the other post works only in PostgreSQL and surely won't work on MySQL. The present answer has been written for MySQL and not tested on PostgreSQL. MySQL and PostgreSQL are very different SQL dialects.
@Jean-François Fabre: Still, maybe you meant that the two posts 'looked' similar. I rephrased this post to take this into account.

Comment: This is still not a good answer.  Its generic and could have come from chatgpt or wiki* (I know it didn't).  Please edit it to to use table and field names that the OP has mentioned.  Customise it to this situation, otherwise it may get deleted again.  And if you are unable to do that, then it is probably not your work.